# Is their way to read jenkins test results irrespective of project types?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

i'm looking for generic solution to read test results from jenkin's irrespective of project type.
project type may java, python, maven etc.
basically i need to fetch the test execution results from jenkin's build.How can i do it.

Comment: If you just want to know "passed" or "failed", you can use the jenkins API for that.

Comment: @jordanm  i want to know the test results like what all test cases are executed and their respective result but  not build result.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins expects JUnit XML files. If your test setup of choice does not produce them, you would have to create them on your own after reading the results in some other format (this shouldn't be incredibly hard..).

But as you are not alone, others probably have done this work for you. For Python, there seems to be the [junit-xml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/junit-xml) package. Its description says:

> Creates JUnit XML test result documents that can be read by tools such as Jenkins

Comment: See also (as an alternative to your answer, not necessarily the original question) https://github.com/xmlrunner/unittest-xml-reporting